# Dapper parameters not working?

Tags: dapper

Dapper 1.34 (on earlier Dapper ver like 1.1x this worked fine).

db.Query(@"Select [whatever] from @TableName Where [PREFIX]='@Prefix' order by [something] desc",
                new { TableName = tableName, Prefix = prefix })

Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the table variable "@TableName".

I get same error trying to define DynamicParameters and passing those.

=======
I am currently doing string substitution {%1} .. but that does not seem acceptable ...

Can I please get a sample, also looking at test class for dapper I cant see it running, maybe something wrong with my project setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that has never worked fine, due to how SQL works:

- table names cannot be parameterized, and dapper has never offered this; that *could* work if you pass in a `DataTable` as a table-valued-parameter, though - which dapper *does* support - but I don't think this is what you are after
- `'@Prefix'` is a string literal; you just mean `@Prefix` (no single quotes)

Comment: Actually the rest didn't matter I got fixated on the Table Name parameter, was thinking it was just a parameter... Figures that the first query I wrote had to have the name passed to it. After trying to pass parameter 20 different ways I gave up thinking it was a bug I would get to later.  It never hit me that I was passing a Table Name...

Comment: Marc, How would I get the a value with out column name. I do something like this: (IDictionary<string, object>)ret.First()).Values.ToList()[0] is there a better way ? PS I am returning 1 column and 1 row in the above, but potentially there would be more rows and columns. How do I iterate it as a table or something.

Comment: @EthernetIP I cannot parse that question; can you rephrase? I can almost certainly answer it, but first I need to understand it...

Comment: @EthernetIP for one column and 1 row; there is an execute scalar method; for one column multiple rows: just query it as the column - `Query<int>(...)` or similar. Beyond that: `Query()` or `Query<dynamic>` or `Query<DapperRow>` all return something that implements a dictionary, as per your example.